# MS Word - Footer On Last Page Only Not Working

Tags: ms-word, footer

I have a document that contains a table with a variable number of rows (populated by an external app). In the footer is another table (not variable number of rows) - this is actually the area where the customer signs, and has a bit of legal verbiage.

I want the footer to appear only on the last page, so I wrapped it in

```
{ IF { PAGE } = { NUMPAGES } "

table is here

" }​
```

The problem is that the footer appears fine if the table in the body doesn't have many rows. It also appears fine if the table in the body has sufficiently many rows that part of it appears on the second page (then the footer table appears on the second page only).

But if the body table has enough rows that the footer table can't fit on page 1 (but not enough rows that some of the body table is pushed to page 2) the footer table doesn't appear at all.

The question is - how do I make it so that if the body table is too big for the footer table to fit on the first page, the footer table prints on the second page?

Comment: This is an end-user, not a programming question and thus belongs on Super User or Microsoft Answers. FWIW try increasing the size of the Footer (Page Layout dialog box).

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38835-footer-last-page-only-not-working.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Also cross-posted at: https://www.office-forums.com/threads/footer-on-last-page-only-not-working.2350293/